# Suppose X is a closed subscheme of Y, with Y locally Noetherian. Is there a locally free resolution of $i_* O_X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I : X \to Y$ be a closed subscheme of a locally Noetherian scheme. I am secretly trying to show that sheaf exts of $i_* O_X$ to coherent sheaves on Y are coherent (in order to find a dualizing sheaf on X) hence I am trying to resolve the left entry by locally frees of finite rank.

I know how to do this if Y is projective, but otherwise I don't know if it is even possible. I know in general that locally free resolutions don't always exist, but maybe the case of an ideal sheaf is special?

I am trying to answer exercise 30.4.A in Ravi Vakils notes.

Comment: Since you only need locally free, you can assume $X,Y$ are affine. Then $i_\ast \mathcal O_X$ is just $A/I$ (where $I$ is the ideal of $X$ in $Y$. $A$ (which is free) surjects onto $A/I$, and the kernel is $I$, which is finitely generated since the schemes are locally noetherian. Hence there is  a free surjection again... (does this work?)

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer that is what I was hoping to do, but I don't see how to glue these local resolutions together.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which shows you need to impose more finiteness conditions for it to possibly work.

Consider the rings
$$R_n = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)} \ \text{for each}\ n \in \mathbf{Z}_{\ge 0}$$
formed by localizing the polynomial ring in $n$ variables at the maximal ideal $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Now consider the scheme:
$$Y = \coprod_n Y_n \ \text{where}\ Y_n := \operatorname{Spec} R_n.$$
Note that the topology on $Y$ is the disjoint union topology, and so the subscheme
$$X = \coprod_n \operatorname{Spec} k$$
formed by choosing the unique closed point in each $\operatorname{Spec} R_n$ is closed.

We claim that $\mathscr{I}_X$, the sheaf of definition of $X$, is such that there does not exist a surjection
$$\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus r} \longrightarrow \mathscr{I}_X \longrightarrow 0$$
for any $r < \infty$, which implies $i_*\mathcal{O}_X$ does not have a resolution by locally free sheaves of finite rank. But taking stalks at the closed point in $Y_n$ gives the exact sequence
$$R_n^{\oplus r} \longrightarrow (x_1,\ldots,x_n)_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)} \longrightarrow 0,$$
which is impossible if $n > r$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea; to make locally Noetherian schemes have non finite behavior, it is a natural idea to take disjoint unions of increasingly big schemes. But I think in this case there is a resolution by locally free sheaves, because we can extend local resolution by zero to different connected components. Do you know what happens if we require the scheme to be Noetherian, or if we relax the assumption that the resolution is finite rank?

Comment: @AreaMan There is the following statement [SGA2, II, Prop. 2.2.7]: A noetherian, separated, locally factorial scheme is such that all coherent sheaves have locally free resolutions (I think of finite rank). This is a slight generalization of a result of Kleiman that is in Hartshorne; see III, Exc. 6.8 and 6.9. But then again, I don't know if assuming the coherent sheaf is a sheaf of ideals helps here or not…

Comment: In the comment above, the reference should be to SGA6, not SGA2.